# Installing Oracle Java in Red Hat Enterprise Linux

Tags: java, oracle, repository

I am seeking advice on a solution for updating Oracle Java in a large number of hosts -

We have a large number of RHEL hosts, and we would like to use yum update rather than rpm install for upgrading Oracle java, as yum update would install the latest version of the java on those hosts, and we can easily automate the version upgrade through using yum update playbooks.

However, my understanding is that yum is a non-standard means of installing Oracle's Java runtimes. Also in order to use yum install, we must have a repository, but Oracle's repository is only available for Oracle Linux rather than RHEL.

Is there any solution where we can use yum update in RHEL with Redhat repository which contains the Oracle Java packages? As I am new to this, any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

[Oracle Java](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/java-se-support-roadmap.html) requires you to be an Oracle customer with a subscription. You will need to contact Oracle sales to figure that out.

Assuming you have a license for it, maybe a repo exists you can use on RHEL. If not, you could repackage their Java as an RPM and create your own repo for private use.

[Red Hat packages OpenJDK](https://developers.redhat.com/oraclejdkalternative) with a [support life cycle](https://access.redhat.com/articles/1299013?extIdCarryOver=true&sc_cid=701f2000001OH6kAAG). This has passed the same test suite, it is Java.  OpenJDK packages are included in RHEL and rebuilds:  `yum list *openjdk*`